# How to confirm whether an image (containing both handwritten and printed texts) contains handwritten text using Google Cloud Vision API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I am using the Cloud Vision API - DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION feature for detecting handwritten text from an image. Although it extracts the handwritten data for me but when it comes to a image with both printed text and handwritten text it is not responding with an identifier which says that this bit is handwritten and this bit is printed. To put it upright the ask is that I want to confirm whether an image has a handwritten text or not. Note - The image may contain only handwritten text or a combination of printed and handwritten text.

If someone can detail what all additional attributes I need to pass to the cloud vision api to achieve the result would be appreciated ? Or is there a way to ask the Cloud Vision API to flag out whether my image contains handwritten data.

Sample Code

```
public class Detect {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
        String filePath = "C:\\Development_Avecto\\images.jpg";
        try {
            detectDocumentText(filePath, System.out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void detectDocumentText(String filePath, PrintStream out) throws Exception, IOException {
        List<AnnotateImageRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        ByteString imgBytes = ByteString.readFrom(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        Image img = Image.newBuilder().setContent(imgBytes).build();
        Feature feat = Feature.newBuilder().setType(Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION).build();
        AnnotateImageRequest request = AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder().addFeatures(feat).setImage(img).build();
        requests.add(request);

        try (ImageAnnotatorClient client = ImageAnnotatorClient.create()) {
            BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = client.batchAnnotateImages(requests);
            List<AnnotateImageResponse> responses = response.getResponsesList();
            client.close();

            for (AnnotateImageResponse res : responses) {
                if (res.hasError()) {
                    out.printf("Error: %s\n", res.getError().getMessage());
                    return;
                }

                TextAnnotation annotation = res.getFullTextAnnotation();
                for (Page page : annotation.getPagesList()) {
                    String pageText = "";
                    for (Block block : page.getBlocksList()) {
                        String blockText = "";
                        for (Paragraph para : block.getParagraphsList()) {
                            String paraText = "";
                            for (Word word : para.getWordsList()) {
                                String wordText = "";
                                for (Symbol symbol : word.getSymbolsList()) {
                                    wordText = wordText + symbol.getText();
                                    out.format("Symbol text: %s (confidence: %f)\n",
                                            symbol.getText(),symbol.getConfidence());
                                }
                                out.format("Word text: %s (confidence: %f)\n\n",wordText, word.getConfidence());
                                paraText = String.format("%s %s", paraText,wordText);
                            }
                            // Output Example using Paragraph:
                            out.println("\nParagraph: \n" + paraText);
                            out.format("Paragraph Confidence: %f\n",para.getConfidence());
                            blockText = blockText + paraText;
                        }
                        pageText = pageText + blockText;
                    }
                }
                out.println("\nComplete annotation:");
                out.println(annotation.getText());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Image - [image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful, this is working sample.

```
    public async Task<string>  GetText(string imgPath,string language,string type)
    {
        TextResult = JsonResult = "";
        var credential = CreateCredential();
        var service = CreateService(credential);
        service.HttpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(1,1,1);
        byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(imgPath);

        BatchAnnotateImagesRequest batchRequest = new BatchAnnotateImagesRequest();
        batchRequest.Requests= new List<AnnotateImageRequest>();
        batchRequest.Requests.Add(new AnnotateImageRequest()
        {
            Features = new List<Feature>() { new Feature() {Type = type, MaxResults = 
      1 },  },
            ImageContext = new ImageContext() { LanguageHints = new List<string>() { 
      language } },
            Image = new Image() { Content = Convert.ToBase64String(file) }
        });            

        var annotate =  service.Images.Annotate(batchRequest);
        BatchAnnotateImagesResponse batchAnnotateImagesResponse = annotate.Execute();            
        if (batchAnnotateImagesResponse.Responses.Any())
        {
            AnnotateImageResponse annotateImageResponse = 
      batchAnnotateImagesResponse.Responses[0];
            if (annotateImageResponse.Error != null)
            {
                if (annotateImageResponse.Error.Message != null)
                    Error = annotateImageResponse.Error.Message;
            }
            else 
            {
                switch (type)
                {
                    case "TEXT_DETECTION":
                        if (annotateImageResponse.TextAnnotations != null && 
        annotateImageResponse.TextAnnotations.Any())
                            TextResult = 
          annotateImageResponse.TextAnnotations[0].Description.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
                        break;
                    case "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION":
                        if (annotateImageResponse.TextAnnotations != null && 
       annotateImageResponse.TextAnnotations.Any())
                            TextResult = 
       annotateImageResponse.TextAnnotations[0].Description.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
                        break;                            
                    case "FACE_DETECTION":
                        if (annotateImageResponse.FaceAnnotations != null && 
           annotateImageResponse.FaceAnnotations.Any())
                            TextResult = 
             JsonConvert.SerializeObject(annotateImageResponse.FaceAnnotations[0]);                            
                        break;
                    case "LOGO_DETECTION":
                        if (annotateImageResponse.LogoAnnotations != null && 
        annotateImageResponse.LogoAnnotations.Any())
                            TextResult = 
       JsonConvert.SerializeObject(annotateImageResponse.LogoAnnotations[0]);
                        break;
                    case "LABEL_DETECTION":
                        if (annotateImageResponse.LabelAnnotations != null && 
      annotateImageResponse.LabelAnnotations.Any())
                            TextResult = 
      JsonConvert.SerializeObject(annotateImageResponse.LabelAnnotations[0]);
                        break;
                    case "LANDMARK_DETECTION":
                        if (annotateImageResponse.LandmarkAnnotations != null && 
       annotateImageResponse.LandmarkAnnotations.Any())
                            TextResult = 
          JsonConvert.SerializeObject(annotateImageResponse.LandmarkAnnotations[0]);
                        break;
                    case "SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION":
                        if (annotateImageResponse.SafeSearchAnnotation != null)
                            TextResult = 
         JsonConvert.SerializeObject(annotateImageResponse.SafeSearchAnnotation);
                        break;
                    case "IMAGE_PROPERTIES":
                        if (annotateImageResponse.ImagePropertiesAnnotation != null)
                            TextResult = 
          
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(annotateImageResponse.ImagePropertiesAnnotation);
                        break;

                }
                
                
            }
        }

        return TextResult;
        
    }
```